# Understanding assembly data segment x86 MASM

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I have some example code for assembly on `x86`, using `MASM` that I am trying to learn from but I'm having a hard time understanding. Here is the following data segment:

```
    .data
sNum1   word    23,-17  
iX      dword   37,54 
sNum2   word    25,-5,3 dup (-17,4)
bVal1   byte    'ABC',3 dup(-1,23) ,35
iNumVals        dword   21,-43,45,167,92,135,-786
bVal2   byte    '345',37,-1
iNum1   dword   ?                           ;user-input first number
iNum2   dword   ?                           ;user-input 2nd number
iSum    dword   ?                           ;sum of user-input values
strPromptName   byte    10,13,"What is your name: ",0
strInput        byte    20 dup(?)           ;holds user-input characters
strGreeting     byte    10,13,9,"Good morning, ",0
strPromptNum    byte    10,13,"Enter a number:",0
strInputNum     byte    12 dup(?)           ;holds input ASCII numbers
strOutputNum    byte    12 dup(?)           ;numeric characters after conversion
strSumIs        byte    10,13,10,13,9,"The output sum is ",0
strArrayIs      byte    10,13,"The values in the array are",0
```

Why are the defined strings that are stored as a `byte` containing numbers before their string value. For Example - `strGreeting` contains "Good morning, ", but is preceded by '10,13,9' and succeeded by a ',0'. What is the purpose/methodology for this? Why are these values here? are they some sort of buffer, and if so, what does each represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10, 13, 9 are character codes—most likely for linefeed (LF), carriage return (CR) and tab. As control characters, they are used to format the output. For example, so the console will look like:

```
What is your name: Tom
        Good morning, Tom
Enter a number:
1
2
3
4

        The output sum is 10
```

(BTW, the usual sequence is CR LF, not LF CR.)

Routines that operation on character sequences often use 0 (NUL) to determine that they've read past the end of the sequence.

It's up to the output routines and console that you run the program in to determine which characters those codes will be interpreted as. In English MS-DOS, the encoding would probably be CP437 (IBM OEM). In English Windows, it would probably be Windows-1252. For the characters you seem to be using, the encodings are identical with ASCII. (Even so, it is very unlikely that your system uses ASCII. It's just an "intentional coincidence.")

Comment: Alright. Great answer but **why** are they necessary is the question I was really wondering. Like for what reason is there `10,13,10,13,9` for `strSumIs`? and what reason do I actually need to add these values?

Answer (score 4):

I think I may have an inkling of your confusion.

Why are they necessary ?

In order to understand that, you have to run the clock back several decades. I'm talking about back in the 1960s and 1950s.

You also need to think in terms of money for a telephone; which was realistically the one and only way to connect computers back then. (Yes, there were the 1% pioneering companies with microwaves, but for the other 99% the phone was the only game in town.)

Now, dig this: way back then, the visual screen was far more expensive than the mechanical printer.  With those kinds of economics in force, it was nothing unusual for a computer operator to sit at a terminal with paper recording every keystroke; and all software producing output on paper itself.

Get this image in your head: I'm not talking about paper output such as the sort to which you may be accustomed these days; no; not a nicely formatted laser or ink jet copy with five fonts and color graphics (ha ha, we didn't even know how to *WISH* for such a machine back then).

Instead, I'm talking about a physical printer which could do these things...

- Print 26 characters
- Print 10 digits
- Print about 15 "Special" characters like: !@#$?*+/

...and that was about it.

Just in case you missed it, those "26 characters" were the upper case "A" thru "Z".  There was no such thing as lower case on those printers.

The printer was a robot typewriter.  Very few people sat in front of a screen back then. Those that did were not quite deified, but definitely ascribed far higher status and "cool dude" attitudes than us mere laity who actually did whatever work was assigned.

Along with this expense and pomp and circumstance was the very real matter of bandwidth.  The printers were most frequently connected to the mainframe computers using a telephone and a modem, and 300 bits per second was considered a "high speed" connection. 120 was frequently used for business purposes.

With all that in context, I am now ready to clarify the confusing "why ?" that is floating around in your head.

The printers of those days were capable of the 51 characters previously mentioned ("A" thru "Z", ten digits, and fifteen "special" symbols).

Many of the printers were designed as adaptations of existing typewriters of the day.

Also understand that the connections were most probably telephones and modems blazing along at 120 bits per second, and some "high speed" lines doing 300.

Now for the critical key to your understanding, ready ? **LONG DISTANCE PHONE BILLS** !!!

How does that all play together ?

The programmers and companies needed a way to tell the printer where to position the print head to strike the paper (through an inked ribbon; not kidding) and for this, they made up three special control characters...

- The Carriage Return
- The Line Feed
- The Tab Character

Later on, they added a pocket full of them; calling the collection "ASCII" (you can google it if you really like history; pretty neat stuff, really, but, back to the topic).

You see, with speeds like that, and such high phone charges, those three characters alone helped to eliminate a significant amount of time on the phone.

i.e., after printing something like...

```
 Parts on way by XYZ Trucking company. Expect Wednesday
```

...which is 55 characters long, you would need as many as 77 blank spaces to get the print head to cycle back to the start.

Another example is the tab key; in which one character eliminates the need for nine consecutive blank spaces.  (Remember, these were all fixed-width fonts; it was a typewriter/robot.)

As a result of all this, messages were formatted in the manner that you are observing. That's the root of all those confusing codes. The printers were very crude by today's standards (but believe me, revered as the high tech wonder boxes  of their day) and as such, needed instructions, each and every time, as to when, where, and how to print the next message.

To get this clearly into your mind, you need to understand just how financially intense all this hoopla was.  One printer, connected via phone, to one computer, as little as 75 miles away, could cost a company, in less than one year,  more than a new car.

Today a printer is probably listed as an office expense. Back then they were amortized as capital equipment.

As we moved from physical paper printers, to display screens (I had a CRT that could heat my room in winter) those original formatting bytes remained useful for programmers; and that's why you see them in use to this day.

Comment: not completely answering the question, but a beautiful bit of history. Thank you for clearing this up for me, that cleared quite a bit of confusion as to how this code protocol came about.

Comment: It is a nice story but the history part where the PC didn't use ASCII, they used the IBM OEM character set (CP437) is missing. (Yes, many character sets are supersets of ASCII, but, there being so many, it is important to know which one you are using.)

Comment: @TomBlodget :  Good point !  (and a +1 from me) As printers dropped in price so that they were less expensive than new cars, they generally used ASCII, with the same general idea that the IBM printers did.

Answer (score 3):

These constants are simply ASCII control codes:

```
 0    \0    NUL
 9    \t    TAB
10    \n    NEW LINE
13    \r    CARRIAGE RETURN
```

'\n', '\r' is an end of line sequence and '\0' is the C end of string marker.

Comment: but why are these values necessary for runtime?